# Install script is not quietly installing exe file

Tags: python, installation, exe

After downloading my for configuring my teams' machines, i attempt to install it in the cmd line by way of:

```
C:\tmp\my.exe /QUIET /VERYSILENT /DIR=C:\sample /TARGETDIR=C:\sample
```

and it will always pop up to the install window.

This is done from within a simple: `os.system(_string_)` call

I know that when i run it with a different EXE file, it WILL install it silently.  Is there something I am missing, or should I be looking deeper at the variables of this exe file more.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: why are you using command line instead of python?

Comment: Is it windows uac that is blocking?

Comment: it seems that when i run the os.system command to reference the install by way of: `os.system(_ABOVE_STRING_)` it will still pop up the windows install wizard.  It seems that some of my other exe files work fine, so i am thinking commands vary on a per install basis?  I thought there are global ones.